# Reflection of EM waves on furniture

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

I just put my phone next to a piece of furniture with wood finish on it. The reflection of the wood on the wood was purple-ish in appearance. What is the Physics behind this?

Comment: Can you provide a photograph of the arrangement?

Comment: What is the light source? Didn't get that, could you clarify, i.e. do you mean some EM radiation of your phone was purple (cannot believe that...) or did you use the cam of your phone?